# Can this usage of native JS Promise result in memory leak in Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, memory-leaks, promise, v8

Here is a sample representation of the code I have. I have a UDP receiver which receives a very high volume of packets continuously. It is stock market live data. That should give some idea about the packet volume.

Based on the data received, an update goes to a Mysql DB and another one to MongoDB. This code however leaks memory like anything and within about 12 minutes crashes with OOM error on an EC2 machine with 7.5GB RAM. This crash is very consistent.

I read several stackoverflow questions and github issues about memory leaks related to Promise chaining or recursively calling Promises. I felt my code did not fit that description and hence want to know if this code will also lead to a memory leak.

When I changed this entire code to work without Promises and only callbacks, memory consumption is close to just 1%. No leak at all.

I am using the current stable version of Node.js (v6.9.5 LTS). Using native Promises, no library like Bluebird etc.

```
const dgram = require('dgram');
const receiver = dgram.createSocket('udp4');
const myObject = require('./myObject.js');

receiver.on('message', function(payload, sender) {
  myObject.processPayload(payload); 
});

receiver.bind(PORT);

// In mObject.js
var myObject = {
  processPayload: function(payload) {
    var updateDoc = doSomethingToPayload(payload);
    // Mongo npm package offers APIs which return a Promise
    var promise1 = this.mongoClient.collection('coll1').update(updateDoc);
    var promise2 = this.getMysqlPromise(updateDoc);
    Promise.all([promise1, promise2]).then(function(values) {
      doSomethingElse();
    }).catch(function(err) {
      doErrorHandling();
    });
  },

  // The mysql npm package does not offer APIs which return a Promise. Hence creating a Promise myself.
  // The mysql2 package does. Tried that too and the same memory leak exists.
  getMysqlPromise: function(updateDoc) {
    var queryStatement = buildQueryFromUpdateDoc(updateDoc);
    var self = this;
    var promise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
      self.MysqlDB.query(queryStatement, function(err, results, fields) {
        if (err) {
          reject(err);
          return;
        }

        resolve(results);
      });
    });
    return promise;
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you really sure, the OOM is caused by promise ? what is the size of your MongoDB database ? I'm not really sure this is caused by Promise.

Comment: There's nothing here that should lead to a memory leak unless some of these promises are never resolved or rejected.  I do notice that there is no way for the caller of `.processPayload()` to know when that function is done with it's async work so that would probably be a problem in how it is used.  It should probably return the promise from `Promise.all()`.

Comment: @SteevePitis I do not know the actual cause of the memory leak. I am trying to find that out. I know for sure that the leak is NOT there when I remove both Mongo and Mysql updates (i.e. comment out those calls). MongoDB isn't huge. The particular collection being used here is around 50K-60K documents and each document is a couple of hundred bytes. I suspect Promise as the cause because without Promises and regular callbacks memory usage is < 1%. Also there were several reports of memory leaks related to Promises

Comment: @jfriend00 The caller of `.processPayload()` need not know about the completion of the async work. That is operating in `fire-and-forget` mode. The completion of the async task is tracked by the `doSomethingElse()`. The promises themselves are getting resolved because there are corresponding logs and they are being seen.

Comment: @brahmana do you have any news on this issue ?

Comment: @Phoenix I did not pursue this line of thought for the issue I was facing. With the help form nodejs irc channel, I was able to figure out that the issue was not memory leak but plain memory consumption and mysql throughput bottleneck. When I reduced the throughput of the program (a.k.a. giving more time between writes to Mysql). This kept the memory usage in check. Turns out the mysql writes were just piling up with Mysql not being able to handle so much writes.